# Manipulating POST variables received via form submit inside Serverside PHP Code

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, http-post

Can I manipulate the POST request inside serverside PHP code ?

I am using PHP and Codeigniter .

I have a function defined inside a controller which receives some data from a FORM via POST .

```
public function primary_fn(){

// Gets called on form submit - POST

// Some Logic 

// Case 1 : call sec_fn1()
// Case 2 : call sec_fn2()
// Case 3 : Call sec_fn3()

}
```

Now I have written several functions inside the models which process the POST Data .

```
public function sec_fn1(){

// Processing POST data

}

public function sec_fn2(){

// Processing POST data

}

public function sec_fn3(){

// Processing POST data

}
```

I am not passing any parameters to the secondary functions . They directly access the values inside the POST request via statements similar to this -

```
$x = $this->input->post('name') ;
```

Now I have some requirement which makes me want to manipulate the data inside the POST request in certain cases.   Since there are too many secondary functions , I dont want to alter their code . Can I manipulate the data inside the POST request from the primary function and let the altered data be used by the secondary functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Can I manipulate the POST request inside serverside PHP code ?
```

Yes, you can. You can set the values of $_POST like any other variable.

```
$_POST['name'] = 'Some new value';
```

Comment: @mad.geek You're welcome. Is that what you were looking for. I've had to do that in CodeIgniter to change values to something else based on other values before doing form validation.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for :) I wasnt sure if you were allowed to manipulate it .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea and it's not a best practices of programming to manipulate global variables manually. $_POST must be used to handle data that is send from browser to server.

Try to create your own global variable to manipulate your data instead of manipulate $_POST directly.